# Momentum for wheel event is cancelled when child element is removed

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to use `onWheel` to implement a list that only renders elements that are in view, but it seems I have to sacrifice momentum scrolling if I want keyed child elements.

See http://jsbin.com/baxajo/1

In this example, you can scroll through a million rows but the momentum scrolling only works outside of the gray area. This is because the row element that was under the cursor when you trigger the wheel gets removed from the DOM. (Were you to omit the key attribute on line 43, the momentum scrolling would work again since this way the row elements are reused rather than removed.)

Is there a way to make a container element be the target of the wheel event, rather than the transient row element?

Suggestions for alternative implementations that would avoid the issue are also welcome, perhaps using `onScroll` instead on `onWheel`?

(Note: mechanism inspired by http://emberjs.com/list-view/)

Comment: It's possible this is also due to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1355, though I'm unsure because I didn't think that onWheel was captured in the way that touch and drag events are.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this in out angularJS application by modifying the ng-repeat. This might not help you, but might help others looking at this problem.

All you need to do is add `track by element.id` in the `ng-repeat`.

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks track by task.id">
```

See: 
http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/